# TypeError: show is not a function ...how to call function for ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I creating a function name `show` in javascript.
but when i call ,that is saying `show` is not a function .
I am creating this for ajax call

### my ajax function..

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            show = function (){
                alert('s');
            $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",              
                        url: ajax_url_store,       
                        data: {action: 'store', views: JSON.stringify(thsirtDesigner.getProduct()) },

                        success: function(data) {
                             if(parseInt(data) > 0) {
                                $( "#cart_pd" ).submit();

                                 }

                        },
                        error: function() {
                            //alert('some error has occured...');
                        },
                        start: function() {
                            //alert('ajax has been started...');    
                        }
                    });
            }

    });
```

Comment: Where is `show` used? You are never calling your code.

Comment: either add a `var` before show `var show = function{...};`, or change your syntax to `function show(){}`

Comment: You are calling show before document.ready get called

Answer (score 1):

With

```
show = function (){
            alert('s');...
```

You don't declare a function named "show". For that purpose, do:

```
function show (){
            alert('s');...
```

Greetz